# Writing a Webservice Client from a WSDL

Tags: java, wsdl, webservice-client

I have a WSDL published on an application server somewhere.  I would like to write a webservice client that uses the WSDL to send requests and recieve responses.  I have not done this before, and most of the tutorials assume you have the code for the webservice.

What is the most straight forward way to do that?

Comment: you want to consume the service, correct?

Comment: I don't do Java but I think you'd start by compiling the classes with javac against the WSDL and every local schema referenced. Then you move on from there to use the interface/port/bindings and everything else. Some Java-addict will need to step up :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jax-ws to generate a client for the web service end point. There is a tool called "wsimport" which will do that for you.

Given a wsdl, it will generate all the client artifacts that you need to call the web service programmatically using Java.

See here for more details- http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html

Answer (score 0):

One way to make these requests is to make an HTTP request passing the appropriate webservice XML in the body of the request. We need to do this regularly with Salesforce.com as it's relatively limited with regards to the WSDLs that it can consume, and so we need to find an easy way to see what the contents of those requests should be. Since you've written the webservice I assume you know what you need to send to it, but if not [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org) is an invaluable tool — it can consume WSDLs and generate example requests which you can then fill in and fire off to test the webservice also. For Java in particular, you'll want to find the WSDL2Java tool to generate classes you can use to call the service with ease.